# I need help translating query builder notation to something eloquent can understand

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2 with homestead. I have the following models: Dar, Activity, Destination, and User. I have cooresponding controller names plus a reportsController. In Tinker, I wrote:

```
$activityByName = DB::table('dars')->select('activity_id',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('activity_id')->get();
=> [
     {#763
       +"activity_id": 1,
       +"total": 2,
     },
     {#764
       +"activity_id": 3,
       +"total": 1,
     },
     {#754
       +"activity_id": 4,
       +"total": 1,
     },
   ]
```

Wonderful, but when I put it in my ReportsController:

```
$activityByName = Dar::with('activity')->select('activity_id')- >raw('count(*) as total')->groupBy('activity_id')->get();
```

This returns:

Driving: 3
    Flying: 3
    Boating: 3

What I want to see is:

Driving: 2
    Flying:  1
    Boating:  1

The "with('activity')" is to display the activity name instead of the value (e.g. driving instead of activity_id: 1). I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the "*withCount*" method:

```
$activityByName=Dar:withCount('activity')->get();
foreach ($dar as $activityByName)
  echo $dar->activity_id . ': ' . $dar->activity_count;
```

The "*withCount*" method generates a new 'field' called *`<related_tablename>_count`*.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
(scroll down to "Counting Relationship Results")

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I've not seen the "counting relationship results".